# What would be the definition of "pivot by" in this context?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, british-english, learning

In this NYTimes Headline:

"Tightening polls, fears about crime and apathy in their base are driving a wave of Democratic hand-wringing and a **pivot by** Gov. Kathy Hochul."

what did author menas by "pivot by"? it would make sense to me if "Pivot by" is "pivot from"

Comment: The specific preposition here has no significance. Gov. Kathy Hochul did a u-turn on some policy issue, but it could just as well be a pivot ***by*** her as ***from*** her. There's not the faintest nuance of difference.

Answer (score 2):

To 'pivot' means *to turn*. In politics, a pivot can mean a change of direction - when a politician or official says or does something the opposite of what they did and said before.

As 'pivot' in this context is the name of an action, it is correct to say the action was performed *by* the named politician or official.

Other similar terms include '*a political u-turn*'.

Answer (score 1):

Gov. Kathy Hochul pivoted.  A pivot "from" could mean that voters are moving away from supporting Gov. Hochul to some other candidate.  Instead what is meant is that Gov. Hochul has changed her strategy to some degree.